# Square of 2-norm

Tags: convex-optimization

This might be silly but how would I solve the following equation for $x$?

$$ \left\| Y - \frac{Z_i}{x} \right\|^2_2 = 2t $$

Comment: Assuming $Y$ and $Z_i$ are simply vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, your equation reads $\sum_{k=1}^n (Y_k - (Z_i)_k/x)^2 = 2t$, which is simply a quadratic equation.

Comment: @filmor I see what you mean - actually, I am trying to minimize this problem : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542907/minimization-of-norms

Comment: @filmor I am not entirely sure how to do reach that conclusion by just taking the derivative and setting to 0.

Comment: Use the inner product definition of the $l_2$ norm, and set the derivative equal to 0.

Comment: I see. Thank-you.

Comment: What are $Y, Z_i,x$ and $t$?. Note let $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\| y\|^2_2= y^Ty$.

Answer (score 0):

Write squared norm as inner product: 
$$\| Y - Z_i/x\|^2 = \|Y\|^2 - \frac{2}{x} \langle Y, Z_i\rangle +\frac{1}{x^2}\|Z_i\|^2  $$
Equating this to $2t$ yields a quadratic equation for $1/x$. (Or a quadratic equation for $x$, if you multiply everything by $x^2$).