# Minimization of norms

Tags: convex-optimization, normed-spaces

How do I minimize the following?

$ min_{z>0} - zt + 1/2\ z\ ||\ Y + X_k\ /\ z\ ||_2^2 $

Also, $X_k^TX_k = 1 \  \ \forall k $

I am given that the answer should be : 
$
\sqrt{Y^T - 2t}  + Y^TX$

But I don't understand how to get this.

Here are my steps so far:

Taking the derivative and setting to $ 0$

$ X_k/z  - Y^TX_k /z - 1/(z^2) = Y^TY - 2t $

But if I were to take the roots of this equation the solution does not come out to be : $
\sqrt{Y^T - 2t}  + Y^TX$

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track; you've made some mistake in your derivative calculation, and notice also that the question is asking you for the *minimum* and not the *minimizer*.

Might as well expand out that inner product:

$$\min_{z>0}\ -zt + \frac{1}{2} z\left(Y^T Y + Y^TX/z + X^TY/z + X^TX/z^2\right)$$
$$\min_{z>0}\ -zt + \frac{1}{2} \left(Y^T Yz + 2 X^TY + 1/z\right).$$
Differentiating I get
$$0 = -t + \frac{1}{2}Y^TY -\frac{1}{2}z^{-2}$$
so
$$z = (Y^T Y -2t)^{-1/2}.$$

Plugging this minimizer into the objective gives me
$$\frac{1}{2}(Y^TY-2t)(Y^TY-2t)^{-1/2} + X^TY + \frac{1}{2}(Y^TY-2t)^{1/2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(Y^TY-2t)^{1/2} + X^TY + \frac{1}{2}(Y^TY-2t)^{1/2}$$
$$\sqrt{(Y^TY-2t)} + X^TY$$

I leave it to you to check that the above critical point is indeed a local minimum, and that this local minimum is global.